# Cross domain HttpWebRequest return 403 forbidden

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, server-side, http-status-code-403

I have 2 sites that sits on 2 domains. I need to send information from one site to the other.
I checked that the asmx is reachable running unit test but when I run my code from the second domain I get a 403 forbidden response.
The code is extremely simple:

```
     try    
     {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.blahblahblah.com/Services/ChatNotification.asmx?fromId=" + 525808 + "&toId=" + 525808);
        var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream(); 
    }
    catch(WebException ex)
    {
         var response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;       
    }
```

Comment: 403 is return from your server side, check your server instead of client

Comment: Maybe check what is sent over the wire.  You may also want to investigate CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) if your call is from the site front-end.